# React with TypeScript - tsconfig file is getting changed automatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsconfig

I have created a React TypeScript project using the following command

```
 npx create-react-app my-app typescript
```

But whenever I run the application using npm start, the tsconfig.json file is automatically changed and the it changes the following jsx parameter from "react" to "react-jsx". And due to this change the entire application in VS Code is throwing an error. I have created the project today and i see the typescript version is latest.

```
"jsx": "react-jsx"
```

Please do let me know how to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: That happened to me as well, it looks like --template typescript it's kinda broke, i haven't actually found a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CRA(create-react-app). In your `.env`, add the following

`DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true` and then restart the server.